# How to get the file name a boost::archive is saving/loading to

Tags: boost, boost-serialization

I was wondering how I could get the **file name string** from an archive, inside the serialize function or any other function that has the `template<class archive>` syntax.

Thanks! =)

Comment: What makes you think an archive has to be serialized to a file?

Comment: @Sam Miller well that's what the end result is....

Comment: no, archives are [serialized to streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/overview.html).

Comment: @Sam: They aren't even serialized to streams; an archive could serialize to anything. The current archive implementations simply use streams, but they don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way of doing what you ask. The [archive concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html) does not require using a file, nor does it even require using a C++ iostream-derived class. All of the libraries archive types use an iostream, but even those don't have to be *file* streams.

You could create your own archive type of course. One specifically for files. Possibly derived from an existing one, passing arguments to the base class. It would have an extra function to get the name of the file that was used to create it.